# How would I extract specific fields and text files with command line arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to be able to extract a column of text from a .txt file, based on a command line argument.

For example, say I have a fruits.txt file like this,

```
Apple Pear Watermelon 
Orange Grapes Banana
```

In the command line, if I were to run `python my_program.py 1 fruits.txt` I want the output to be just the first column, 
E.g.

```
Apple
Orange
```

If it was `python my_program.py 3 fruits.txt`, I would expect the output,

```
Watermelon 
Banana
```

And say I happen to also have a veg.txt file with the same format... e.g.

```
Broccoli Cabbage Asparagus
Spinach Rocket Cucumber
```

Then in the command line, I would expect the same to happen if I did `python 2 veg.txt` 
And get,

```
Cabbage 
Rocket
```

So far I've only figured out how to do it statically. I.e. I have to hard code in
`file = open("fruits.txt", "r")` and specifically printing the field.

E.g.

```
file = open("fruits.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    fields = line.split(" ")

    col1 = fields[0]
    col2 = fields[1]
    col3 = fields[2]
    col4 = fields[3]

    print(col1)

file.close()
```

Comment: Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argv` from `os` module.

```
print_col.py:

import os

column, filename = os.argv[1:3]  # check the actually number of command arguments

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    print([line.split()[column - 1] for line in f.readlines()])  # make sure the column number doesn't beyond the actually column count in the file
```

You can call this script with this command `python print_col.py 1 test.txt`.